# can not get list of task manager process properly

Tags: java

I am using a piece of code to get the process of task manager on windows based system so that i can find that if my desktop based application's instance is running or not. The code is just working fine, here is my code.

```
private static void getAppInstancesCountAlreadyRunning() throws Exception {

    int isApplicationRunning = 0;
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    System.getenv("windir") + "/system32/" + "tasklist.exe");

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        logger.info("....... line read ... "+line);         
        if (line.contains("AppNameHere")) {// || line.contains("javaw.exe")
            logger.info("....... Already running @ " + line);
            isApplicationRunning++;
        }
    }
    input.close();

    if (isApplicationRunning > 1) {
        //Some code here....
    }
}
```

**Issue is:**  I tried it to different many system having windows XP and 7, but on one system i am not getting the process list, i think line

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") + "/system32/" +
 "tasklist.exe");
```

is not giving proper list can someone tell what is the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the full path to run this process just do `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist");`

Also you would need to consider that the tasklist might not be installed.

Comment: Yes it is the same issue i just checked it on the both systems, can you please give some solution of the problem ??

Comment: did you check if the tasklist process exist in the system? if yes, maybe your java app doesnt have permission to run this process... try running it as admin

Comment: no i just checked the tasklist process in the culprit system and it is not there, i already checked the rights issue and the user have admin right at that system, for sure it is the issue of tasklist process as it is not there. Any help for this ?

Comment: not any good help... you could try to store in a file when the process is started and then use it to check, but this is not good because if the computer is restarted, it will show that the process is still running... there would be a logic to work around this restart issue, but as I said 'work around' lol

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the reason (might be 32/64 bit version issues, permissions of executing user, security etc), but I'd say that there are much better ways to achieve this. Your current approach will match against most java applications, many of which run using javaw.exe.

Instead, why not consider writing a file to disk when starting the application, so additional invocations can check for this. This approach is also more friendly when it comes to running in multiple operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea, will try to implement it. +1 for the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

System.getenv(String path), tries to get the value of path, where path is an environment variable. If windir is not defined among the env variables, System.getenv(String path) won't be able to return anythwing.

Comment: let me check this thing, but if it is same as you are saying then what is its solution ???

Comment: i just check the environment variable and the variable is already set  over there, it means that is not the issue, fmodos's answer is more batter as that utility is not installed in the culprit system. Thanks for your answer